# Determining the value of the nth term in this triangle

Tags: arithmetic

So I have this issue here with a certain sequence or rather group of sequences.

The number triangle is as follows,

$7$

$4$ $8$

$2$  $5$  $9$

$1$  $3$  $6$  $10$

I've realized that the bottom row is triangle numbers, with $(x(x+1))/2$

The first column is supposed to be $(n(n+1))/2 + 1$

The issue I'm having with is determining nth terms for the whole triangle, assuming it goes on for even larger numbers. For example, if 1 is at the position $(1,1)$, what steps can I take to locate other numbers, such as a number at the position $(4,8)$. I've tried to find equations for rows or columns, but I keep getting separate ones rather than a consistent algorithm.

Thanks.

Comment: Other than the left most column and bottom row, how are you determining the numbers?  Where do the $5$ and $9$ come from, for example?

Comment: Try thinking in diagonals. For example, $9$ is at $(3,2)$, whereas $8$ is at $(2,3)$ and $7$ is at $(1, 4)$.

Comment: @TobyMak Yeah I've noticed that the numbers on the diagonals are consecutive. But I'm stuck at that point.

Comment: @saulspatz This triangle was given to me as an assignment if that's what you mean.